# Why does SyncToy backup all folders except for one?

Tags: backup, synctoy

I have noticed that when I do a full backup over the weekend, it backs up for all the folders except for one.

I thought that it could be taking to long to do the backup and it ends on Monday when someone starts using the files, so I renamed the Folder Pair name in SyncToy hoping that it will run first. I'm not sure if it does but it still doesn't backup anything into that folder.

Comment: What settings does the folder pair have?  and does the folder have anykind of special name?  also does running the folder pair manually and checking the preview give any clues?

Comment: The Folder Pair is the same as the others, Echo.. The name is just a normal name.. I just ran the manual backup and it got 20 errors, saying; Error: Cannot read from the source file "File path". The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. We run the backups late at night when no one is using it, but it is probably saying it now because people are using the files

Comment: What specific folder is the program not operating on?

Comment: Its a folder that has SQL server backups and databases

Answer (score 1):

If your SQL Server is still running it will hold a reservation on the files. You would need to stop SQL Server before synctoy could copy off those files.

Also its worth noting that even if synctoy were copying the sql server database files it would most likely not be providing a usable backup.

If you wish to backup an SQL Server database you should run a backup schedule from within SQL Server Manager then copy off just the backup files. Don't use synctoy against the SQL server database files directly

Comment: Ok thanks for that, we are also doing that as well (someone else had previously setup for those SQL database files to backup). But nothing gets backed up into this folder, none of the SQL backup files and anything else in there.. then I back it up manually on Monday and it backs up fine during the week

Comment: Because we change the HDD's over every Friday and the HDD is empty